# django model get_absolute_url isn't working properly after url refactoring

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm having problems with my get_absolute_url in my Entry model. The problem is that since I decoupled the urls.py of my app this method shows the url of the current page I'm visiting. So where it should display a list of the urls of the different entries it actually displays http://localhost:8000/weblog/. If any of you guys has some spare time please [check the code here](http://dpaste.com/645466/).

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `get_absolute_url` is returning empty, making your hrefs `""`, which will simply link to the current page. I would have thought the `permalink` decorator would generate an error if it couldn't reverse the URL properly, but apparently not.

Looking over your code, the only thing I can find that's out of sorts is that you're referencing the `slug` attribute with `slug()`, as if it was a method. My best guess is that this is what is killing the reverse URL lookup.

Comment: wow, you've got pretty sharp debugging skills...that was it, the slug attribute was marked as if it were a method. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you code must be this:

models.py

```
@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
     return ...
```

And, this is important, in your urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_info_dict, name='coltrane_entry_detail'),
```

Comment: Decorators don't have to use the special decorator syntax (`@permanlink`). What he has is fine.

Comment: adding "name=" ?? That didn't work. And the decorator syntax isn't the issue either. I wished there was an easy way to see from the template the properties and methods of each entry...something like php's var_dump()